# How to create a reactive "calculated field" using Shiny / ggplot2 / dplyr?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dplyr

I'm trying to create a Shiny app that does the following:
1) use a reactive input field to dynamically select a dimension (x variable),
2) use dplyr to then create a subset of the data aggregated by that dimension,
3) then use multiple fields to calculate a new y variable.

I've tried a bunch of different ways, but can't find a way to make it all work...

Here's what the code looks like so far (on the server.R side)...

```
output$MyChart <- renderPlot({

d <- MyData #%>%
    group_by(input$Dim1) %>%
    summarize("Metric3" = sum(Metric1) / sum(Metric2))

p <- ggplot(d, aes(x = d[,input$Dim1], y = d$Metric3))
p + geom_bar(stat = "identity")

})
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post more verbose code as well as an example of the output you want

Comment: You should look into group_by_ (or, rather all verbs in dplyr with an underline at the end). These use standard evaluation and allow you to pass things like input$Dim1. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html